# How to convert Timestamp Dates into Integer Values

Tags: python, dataframe, timestamp, integer, typeerror

i have the following set up:

I want to store data from yfinance Dataframe in two list´s that represent the X and Y Values. This is achieved by following lines:

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


stock = 'TSLA'
start = '2020-11-01'


df = yf.download(stock , start=start)

nfx = []
nfy = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    x_data = nfx.append(index)
    y_data = nfy.append(row['Close'])
```

Now I want to feed these X and Y Values into a Polyfit Function.
To do this I need to have them somehow as Integers.

How can I realize this idea?
When i tried the following approach:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    x_data = nfx.append(np.asarray(index).astype(float))
    y_data = nfy.append(row['Close'])
```

, i got the Error Message:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

What am i missing here?

Thanks a lot,
Benjamin

Comment: dont use a loop to fill x_data and y_data. you can just do `x_data = df.index` and `y_data = df['Close']`. what type is the index of your dataframe? depending on that type you have different possibilities to change the date to a number

Comment: okay, thanks, that seems allready like an improvement. However i need to convert the timestamps into Integers ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using Unix timestamps.

```py
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow() # now is a datetime object
print(now.timestamp()) # seconds since Unix epoch, it's a float however
1633081223.677152

print(int(now.timestamp())) # seconds have been converted to integers
1633081223
```

Or you could use [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to convert the datetime object into some string you could then use `int()` on.

---

If you have strings in your index, you can use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert them to datetime objects which you can then use to get Unix timestamps like above.

```py
obj = datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-11-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
obj.timestamp() # now available
```

Comment: okay i get the idea but what is the "now" variable supposed to be in my example? how can i apply your steps?

Comment: Oh, for some reason I thought you had datetime objects in your index. If you have strings you can use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert the string dates you have into datetime objects, then they would be the same type as `now` in my example.